# Parts of string in regex

Tags: c#, regex, split

how to cut bold part of string with Regex?

wmq://**aster-C1.it.google.net**@**EO_B2**:**1427**/**QM.0021**?queue=**SOMEQueue**?

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: What did you tried? What do you mean by 15 chars?

Comment: I must write min 15 chars, in another way comment will not save. 

I dont know how to start from (wmq://) and and after "@".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var myUrl     = "wmq://aster-C1.it.google.net@EO_B2:1427/QM.0021?queue=SOMEQueue?";
var myRegex   = new Regex(@"wmq://(.*?)@(.*?)\?queue=(.*?)\?");
var myMatches = myRegex.Match(myUrl);

Debug.Print(myMatches.Groups[1].Value);
Debug.Print(myMatches.Groups[2].Value);
Debug.Print(myMatches.Groups[3].Value);
```

But you may need to change it a bit for variations in the url.

There are proper tutorials on the web to explain Regex, but here is some quick info:

- @ before a string "" in C# avoids the need to escape the blackslashes.
- (brackets) are the capture groups, so "() ()" becomes groups[1] groups[2].
- .*? means match anything, but do an ungreedy minimal match.
- \? the backslash says match the question mark instead of it being a special character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Uri`

```
var uri = new Uri(@"wmq://aster-C1.it.google.net@EO_B2:1427/QM.0021?queue=SOMEQueue?");

var a = uri.UserInfo;
var b = uri.Host;
var c = uri.Port;
var d = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
var e = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)["queue"];
```

Comment: I dont have this method, this is silverlight 5 app :(

Comment: @user3763161 That's irrelevant; you should still have access to System.Uri.